# Rails proxy controller not pulling images through properly, how to modify appropriately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having to implement a proxy on a Rails 3.1 app to overcome some cross-domain JS issues.

So far I have it retrieving web page text source seemingly right, however it commonly misses images (perhaps relative paths?) in the page and then when I direct it with an absolute path to an image it will show the [ascii encoding of the image](https://img.skitch.com/20120117-nk6b7gjagjmrppk2iyjp91hg66.jpg) rather than the image itself, I think for obvious reasons from the code for someone familiar with the topic.

I was hopeful that someone would be able to revise the following code so as to work also properly with an image proxy situation:

**proxy_controller.rb:**

```
class ProxyController < ApplicationController
  def get
    url = URI.parse(params["url"])
    result = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
      render :text => result.body
  end
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
get "proxy" => "proxy#get", :as => "proxy"
```

**Calling it via:**

```
http://<my_dev_server>/proxy?url=http://<somedomain.tld>/path/to/page/images/image.jpg
```

or

```
http://<my_dev_server>/proxy?url=http://<somedomain.tld>/path/to/page
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

instead of render, use [send_data](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data)

Comment: Okay, yes, that seems that it can do the trick, however each attempt so far with this has lead simply to a direct download of a file vs loading the image into the browser or loading a web page into the browser.  It may not ultimately be a big deal, but my goal is to pass it through nokogiri to pull a specific filename out that needs to be manipulated.

Comment: you need to set the correct content type so that the browser knows how to handle the incoming content...

Comment: So for example, in this case, it seems as though I cannot have a multipurpose proxy, ie I will need to create an `image_proxy` and a `general_proxy` vs a catch all if I understand you correctly?

Comment: You mean -- you will need to return different content types for different requests through the proxy?  yes.  Though you may be able to detect the content type of the requested data and reflect that back to the client.

Comment: Alright, yes that did indeed to the trick I needed.  By modifying the original render line to: `send_data result.body, :type => result.content_type, :disposition => 'inline'` I was able to accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should use base64 encode if you will show this get on html

```
send_data Base64.encode64(result.body), type: result.content_type, disposition: 'inline'
```

and in your html and javascript request using

```
$('#image-wrapper').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />')
```