# How to display a cross domain site in an iframe and retain it's ajax functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, iframe

I am writing an application that will enable the user to create MVT tests for their website. To enable a user to create their tests I need to display the users site in my application, and access the DOM of the iframe with javascript.

I am currently using an iframe to display the third party website. The src url is to a proxy controller which accepts the third party website URL as a parameter.

```
...
<iframe src="<%= raw proxy_path(experiment: {url: @experiment.page_url}) %>"></iframe>
...
```

The Proxy controller gets the page and replaces all relative urls in the page with absolute urls, so assets, etc are retreived.

```
class ProxiesController < ApplicationController

  # Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891161/rails-proxy-controller-not-pulling-images-through-properly-how-to-modify-approp
 def get
    url = URI.parse(params.require(:experiment).permit(:url)[:url])
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
    response.body = response.body.gsub(/(href=")(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)/, "href=\"#{url}" )
    response.body = response.body.gsub(/(src=")(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)/, "src=\"#{url}" )
    render html: response.body.html_safe
  end
```

This pretty much completely works except for any ajax calls made within js files. For example I am getting this error in Chromes Dev Tools console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/pws/ssnJavascript.jsp 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:18
```

The error in the rails server is:

```
Started GET "/pws/ssnJavascript.jsp" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-09 13:27:57 +0000
source=rack-timeout id=56e08f0a901bc525190eb91ae8925f39 timeout=15000ms service=25ms state=active

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/pws/ssnJavascript.jsp"):
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0.beta4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0.beta4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  rack-timeout (0.1.0) lib/rack/timeout.rb:104:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta4) lib/rails/application.rb:161:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lint.rb:49:in `_call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /home/martinbaillie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/martinbaillie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/martinbaillie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:13:27:58 +0000] "GET /pws/ssnJavascript.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 5564 0.0676
  Rendered /home/martinbaillie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@evolve/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /home/martinbaillie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@evolve/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.text.erb (12.5ms)
source=rack-timeout id=56e08f0a901bc525190eb91ae8925f39 timeout=15000ms service=66ms state=completed
source=rack-timeout id=6432326a16ba57fd4ee477348df43e06 timeout=15000ms state=ready
```

First question: How would I ensure that ajax calls in external JS files are successful?

Second question: Is there a better, more rails,  way of doing this altogether?

Comment: i worked on a project that was similar. It required intercepting all XMLHttpRequest and having another proxy for those requests that would in turn use CURL to retrieve data

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for your comment. Was it a rails application you were working on?

Comment: no, was done in php but the XMLHttpRequest needs to be intercepted in client (javascript) then modify request url to point at your proxy in rails

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try a javascript solution.